# HTML image won't fill table

Tags: html

I have a 2x3 table, image on the left and text on the right with that layout staggered down the table.

When inserting an imagine in the table row it wont fill the section, it adds padding to the edges and is smaller than the table data next to it even though it is the size of the table row. The table data which contains text and a background color is bigger. Spacing within the table is off.

Any way to make the image fill the whole table cell and not add the extra space?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As your question stands right now, it's impossible to answer.  Please see [ask], specifically how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Could you please add your code to your post by editing and clicking the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" insert button (looks like < >)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `td` a background image with the `background-image` CSS property.

```css
td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}
tr{
 border:2px solid grey;
}
.imgcontainer{
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="imgcontainer">
</td>
<td>Table Cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? :D

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table td img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="50%"/>
    <col width="50%"/>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x20"></td>
    <td>Text<br/>Over<br/>Multiple<br/>lines</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x50"></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```